# How to escape all regex special chars but not all at once (by Pattern.quote()), just one-by one

Tags: java, regex

Here's the problem: user is presented with a text field, unto which may he or she type the filter. A filter, to filter unfiltered data. User, experiencing an Oracle Forms brainwashing, excpets no special characters other than %, which I guess more or less stands for ".*" regex in Java.

If the User Person is well behaved, given person will type stuff like "CTHULH%", in which case I may construct a pattern:

```
Pattern.compile(inputText.replaceAll("%", ".*"));
```

But if the User Person hails from Innsmouth, insurmountably will he type ".+\[a-#$%^&*(" destroying my scheme with a few simple keystrokes. This will not work:

```
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(inputText).replaceAll("%", ".*"));
```

as it will put \Q at the beginning and \E at the end of the String, rendereing my % -> .* switch moot.

The question is: do I have to look up every special character in the Pattern code and escape it myself by adding "\\" in front, or can this be done automagically? Or am I so deep into the problem, I'm omitting some obvious way of resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(inputText).replaceAll("%", "\\E.*\\Q"));`?

This should result in the following pattern:

```
input:   ".+\[a-#$%^&*(" 
quote:   \Q".+\[a-#$%^&*("\E 
replace: \Q".+\[a-#$\E.*\Q^&*("\E
```

In case the `%` character was the first or last character you would get a `\Q\E` (if you only have the input `%` the expression would end up being `\Q\E.*\Q\E`)  but this should still be a valid expression.

*Update*:

I forgot the difference between `replace(...)` and `replaceAll(...)`: the replacement parameter in the former is a literal while the replacement in the latter is an expression itself. Thus - as you already stated in your comment - you need to call `Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(inputText).replaceAll("%", "\\\\E.*\\\\Q"));` (quote the backslashes in the string and in the expression).

From the documentation on `String#replaceAll(...)`:

> Note that backslashes in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string.

Comment: +1 But I'm not sure that the documentation for the `quote` method *guarantees* that a string will always be surrounded by `\Q` and `\E` (it says only "This method produces a String that can be used to create a Pattern that would match the string s as if it were a literal pattern."). Though in practice I think all currently existing impementations of Java do use the `\Q...\E` approach to achieve this.

Comment: @Thomas excuse the newbie question - what is the custom here? Do I delete my comments when you update the answer?

Comment: @pafauk. Hmm, I'm not sure but if the comments don't provide any additional information (which I think is true of our comments now), I'd delete them to keep the post clear. I'll start and delete my previous comments.

Answer (score 6):

I think this algorithm should work for you:

- Split on `%`
- Quote each part separately using `Pattern.quote`
- Join the string using `.*`

Comment: Thanks! Nice and clean, although needs some work remembering if there was a % at the start and/or the end of the String.